# TypeScript: type inference when using Array.find

Tags: typescript

why the `env` can't be a `enum type` contains all items of list, and how?

```
const { hostname, pathname } = window.location
const rootDir = pathname.split('/')[1]
const list = ['newstage', 'stage', 'qa3', 'qa2', 't1', 'sit', 'dev']
const env = list.find(el => rootDir === el)
```

now `env` is `const env: string`, what I want is
`const env: "stage" | "qa3" | "qa2" | "t1" | "sit" | "dev"`

Comment: To clarify your issue, please provide the type of `rootdir` which , from the code above, looks like a simple string.  Also,  provide the exact error you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [const
assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

> no literal types in that expression should be widened (e.g. no going from "hello" to string)

```
const rootDir = 'qa3';
const list = ['newstage', 'stage', 'qa3', 'qa2', 't1', 'sit', 'dev'] as const;
const item = list.find(el => rootDir === el)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiEUAiBLOMC8MDkBHAQwGYcBuAKFElgBtVosYBtHMAUwHdoCBzNnADS5ufQbkIkh+AgCYxOKAEZ5EVFHkATNgDccAXRgEIMKtAqnYatgFtGdaADoAZqjAaAFGxpYAfPEQo6FiY2F4AlEA)